# Modifying innerhtml properties at runtime

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, innerhtml

I have a dropdownlist with two values and a text box. What I want is-
 - If I select option 1, the text box should be like that atmost 10 characters can be entered
 - If I select option 2, there should be no limit on maxlength for textbox

I am not sure how it could be done. May be by modifying the innerhtml but dont know how to proceed! Below is my .jsp file code for dropdown and textbox which as of now displays textbox of maxlength 10 which I need to make dynamic.

```
<select name="filetype" id="3">
     <option value="null">--</option>
     <option value="CTN" >CTN</option>
     <option value="SLID" >SLID</option>
</select>

<h2>Enter the number<font color="red">*</font></h2>
        <input type="text" name="customerID" maxlength=10 size="50" id="4"/> 
        <input type="submit" value="Submit Data" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you tag this question with [jquery](/questions/tagged/jquery) here you are a simple example how to achieve that:

```
 $('input[name="customerID"]').attr('maxlength')
```

This is a getter. To set a value you must to write second parameter. The whole example should be:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('select[name="filetype"]').on('change', function(e) {
    var val = $(this).val();
    if(val === "CTN") {
      $('input[name="customerID"]').attr('maxlength', 10); //maxlength =10
    } else if(val === "SLID") {
      $('input[name="customerID"]').removeAttr('maxlength'); //no maxlength
    }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

with some JQuery something like this could works:

```
$("h2 input").attr({maxlength: 30});
```

Comment: That's wrong. If you set a parameter needs `{}` syntax

Answer (score 0):

Write an `onchange` event to `select` as below. Get the `selected value` and based on the condition add or remove `maxlength` attribute to/from `textbox`

```js
$("select[name=filetype]").on('change', function() {
  var val = $(this).find('option:selected').val();
  $('input[name="customerID"]').val('');
  if (val == "CTN")
    $('input[name="customerID"]').attr('maxlength', 10);
  else if (val == "SLID")
    $('input[name="customerID"]').removeAttr('maxlength');
  else
    return false;
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="filetype" id="3">
  <option value="null">--</option>
  <option value="CTN">CTN</option>
  <option value="SLID">SLID</option>
</select>

<h2>Enter the number<font color="red">*</font></h2>
<input type="text" name="customerID" maxlength="10" size="50" id="4" />
<input type="submit" value="Submit Data" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code below.

```
<script>
$(function () {
    $('select').change(function () {
        if ($(this).val() == "CTN") {
            $('input:first').attr('maxlength', '10')
        }
        else if ($(this).val() == "SLID") {
            $('input:first').attr('maxlength', '')
        }
    });
});
</script>
<select name="filetype" id="3">
    <option value="null">--</option>
    <option value="CTN">CTN</option>
    <option value="SLID">SLID</option>
</select>

<h2>Enter the number<font color="red">*</font></h2>
<input type="text" name="customerID" maxlength="10" size="50" id="4" />
<input type="submit" value="Submit Data" />
```